# Can I migrate a Mercurial repo from Bitbucket to a VPS?

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket, vps

I've been using a shared host and Bitbucket + Hg for several years. At the end of this year I plan to migrate the site to a VPS and want to host a private Mercurial instance on the same VPS. Is it possible to migrate the repo and its entire history from Bitbucket to the new VPS Mercurial instance or must I just do a big push from the default trunk and lose all the old branches and what not?

I see a lot of posts about migrating INTO Bitbucket but none about migrating OUT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you always have the whole history of changes (not entirely true, but in most cases).

It means that you can push the whole repository (which includes all the history) to any other repository.

That's it: you just create an empty repository anywhere you like and `push` to it.

Comment: Pushing to a new empty repo includes the changes and not just the current set of files on disk?

Comment: In the `.hg` directory there are all the revisions ever made. `push` command pushes the difference between current repository and remote repository. Difference between current and empty - is entire repository.

Comment: Ok, my understanding of Mercurial was too shallow. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewHeath: try it out locally! Create a new empty repository with `hg init` and test that you can push to it from another repository: `hg push /path/to/my/empty/repo`. You'll see that `hg log` in the new repo lists all the commits, i.e., `hg push` transferred the history into the empty repo.